# HtmlCompressor() Preserve id field in the elements

Tags: java

I have a situation where I am using HtmlCompressor() in Java and running
htmlCompressor.compress(“html string”)
But it removes id from my <img id=example …/> tag. How can I set it to preserve this id field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try : `htmlCompressor.compress("<img id= 'example' src =' source-here'/>")`

Comment: I did this and it removed the id